# q.js automatically propagate errors (catch async thrown errors)?

Tags: q

i would like to know if there's any way to automatically propagate errors from a promise to another?   IE:  catch the thrown error from a nested promise.

for example, in the following code sample, the "internalWorker" nested promise function needs

`.fail(function (error) {
            return deferred.reject(error);
        });`

in order to  propagate the error.  if this line isn't contained, the error is throw to the top. (crashed app)

would it be possible to automatically propagate the error so i don't need to add .fail() functions to all my nested promises?

```

```
function top(input) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    internalWorker(input).then(function (value) {
        logger.inspectDebug("top success", value);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        return deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

function internalWorker(input) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    q.delay(100).then(function () {
        throw new Error("internal worker async error");
    }).fail(function (error) {
        return deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

top("hello").then(function (value) {
    logger.inspectDebug("outside success", value);
}).fail(function (error) {
    logger.inspectDebug("outside fail", error);
}).done();
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using https://github.com/kriskowal/q, this will do what you intend:

```
function top(input) {
    return internalWorker(input).then(function (value) {
        logger.inspectDebug("top success", value);
        return value;
    });
}

function internalWorker(input) {
    return q.delay(100).then(function () {
        throw new Error("internal worker async error");
        return value;
    });
}

top("hello").then(function (value) {
    logger.inspectDebug("outside success", value);
}, function (error) {
    logger.inspectDebug("outside fail", error);
}).done();
```

Return promises or values from within callbacks. Errors propagate implicitly.

Comment: thank you!  as your solution describes, and what i see from reading the typescript definition of q.d.ts:   promise.then() and promise.fail() will allow the nesting of promises (or wraps the value in a promise if it isn't a promise already)

that's great!  now that i understand q, it reduces my code by about 66% (removal of error handling for the mid-level functions)

the docs are a bit hard to understand for beginners (like me) ...  but now that I understand it, I can't ever go back!